# Disable Login with Google

Tags: google-chrome

Even if you disable Chrome's automatic sign-in in the browser's settings:

[image]

Google seems to follow you when a website offers Login with Google:
[image]

Is there a way to disable Login with Google at all for external websites?

Comment: There really should be. If you log out of your google account (e.g, after done with gmail, click in top right and choose sign out), it will go away. But it is absurd that you are constantly one accidental tap/click away from disclosing your name and email to a random site and having an account created with them. I ended up with an ebay account for my work email the other day.... grrr...

Answer (score 17):

This feature is called [one-tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/). Its documentation seems to be gone from the website, but [StackOverflow has some points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53056300/documentation-for-the-automatic-continue-as-google-popup). The script in charge is https://smartlock.google.com/client. If you have an adblock extension or something like Greasemonkey, you can block it.

If you want to get rid of the [button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) too, you can block https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js.

Comment: As of 2020, the following uBlock Origin expression blocks that `accounts.google.com/gsi/iframe/$subdocument`

Comment: As of 2023, this answer worked with uBlock Origin  https://superuser.com/a/1773215/142948

Answer (score -1):

Not really sure if this is what you're referring, but I have had similar issues with inconsistencies when signing to sites with Google account, so I disabled the cookie jar/browser consistency.

I reckon perhaps this has to do with a flag in Chrome's settings - `#account-consistency`

Do the following to resolve:

> - Load `chrome://flags/#account-consistency` in the browser's address bar. Google Chrome should display the flag Identity consistency
>     between browser and cookie jar at the top.
> - Set the flag to disabled with a click on the menu and selecting disabled from the context menu.
> - Restart the Chrome browser.

**Acknowledgements**

[Martin Brinkmann: Disable the sign-out link between Chrome, Gmail and other Google services](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/09/08/disable-the-sign-out-link-between-chrome-gmail-and-other-google-services/)