# How to permanently block 'Sign in with Google' suggestions from websites?

Tags: firefox, login, website

Some websites pop-up a message suggesting *Sign in to 'me' with Google*:

[image]

Examples:

- medium.com seems to do this once (the setting is stored in a cookie; when I remove that the pop-up appears again);
- pinterest.com keeps nagging me everytime I follow a link to it (often from a Google image search).

**How can I block these suggestions, from *any* website from now on?**
My Google-Fu fails me here because most search results are about *Google search suggestions* or *automatically logging in with Google*.

Notes:

- I'm always logged into Google and want to keep that;
- I'm using FireFox;
- I'm using AdBlock plus, maybe there's something I can configure there?

Comment: My question now points to a duplicate (fine) that in itself has close votes pointing to another duplicate (not fine). I would have preferred the *second* link as the duplicate (it explains *one-tap* better too). Having said that, none of these two questions answers the pinterest.com case. I have added [an additional answer](https://superuser.com/a/1495482/141909) to that second ('Yolo') question and added another duplicate close vote to the first question.

Comment: Yeah, the closing is a mess. Technically, timewise, the second is a duplicate of the first, but apparently @pkamb thinks otherwise. :-)

Comment: This has the answer that works for me: https://superuser.com/a/1550237/37578

Comment: This worked for me https://superuser.com/a/1773215/142948

Answer (score 5):

uBlock Origin extension for Firefox can be used to block specific items. Within uBlock Origin running:

- Right-click on the popup (or overlay).
- Select `Block element...`
- A filter editor will show the rule to be created; click on `Create`.

If successful, next time *that particular page* is loaded, the overly should be blocked.

Note that it may take a few times to completely block all elements of the overlay.

Comment: As for what to block, see also https://superuser.com/questions/1413748/disable-login-with-google/1439999#1439999

Comment: What do you mean with "newer version"? ublock origin works just fine here.

Comment: As of May 2023, this is the solutions works: https://superuser.com/questions/1773208/how-can-i-block-the-sign-in-with-google-prompt-on-websites/1773215#1773215