# How can I block the “Sign in with Google” prompt on websites?

Tags: firefox, browser, login, prompt, adblock

On many websites that require login, those annoying Google login prompts appear:

[image: "Sign in to unlock deals and discounts!" popup]

There are several tutorials on the Internet on how to avoid this, for example, [this one on How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/735152/how-to-turn-off-the-sign-in-with-google-prompt-on-websites/), which suggest disabling an option in the Google account. However, this doesn't work, since mine is not enabled and never was:

[image: "Allow Google to offer a faster way to sign in with your Google Account on supported third-party sites" (in German)]

Note, that this only happens with Firefox (110.0.1 (64-bit), AdBlocker ultimate v 3.7.21 installed); if I use the Brave browser (version 1.49.120 Chromium: 111.0.5563.64 (Official Build) (64-bit)), which is known to block ads by default, they are not displayed. I'm on [Ubuntu 22.04.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_22.04_LTS_(Jammy_Jellyfish)) LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) with Linux kernel 5.19.0-35-generic x86_64.

Comment: Note that the "disabling an option in the Google account" is not a possibility if you use firstparty-isolate or any other privacy features that prevent embeds like this from seeing your Google session cookie. This is another motivation to want a way to block it browser-side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Google One Tap sign-up prompts?](https://superuser.com/questions/1414410/how-to-disable-google-one-tap-sign-up-prompts)

Comment: What kernel version? They [recently forced-updated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkyQhfhf048&t=2m36s) (within the last few weeks or months) 22.04 to [HWE](https://ubuntu.com/kernel/lifecycle) (it broke [a USB 2 workaround for a particular motherboard](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2022/07/20/enabling-both-usb-3-and-usb-2-ports-for-a-ga-970a-ds3p-motherboard/) I was relying on). Use `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic` to install the latest LTS kernel and use (e.g.) GRUB_DEFAULT="1>4" in file `/etc/default/grub` to change the ***default*** GRUB menu item to the LTS kernel one

Comment: @PeterMortensen Linux 5.19.0-35-generic x86_64

Answer (score 76, accepted):

[uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/)
worked better for the poster, with this added to the filters section:

```
accounts.google.com/gsi/*
```

Click on the three gears in uBlock Origin, then go over to "My Filters" and paste the above line into the page below and then click "Apply Changes".

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer - many of the answers to this problem start by saying "well, first, you sign in to your google account..." :sigh: This seems to work for me.

Comment: For those new to this, click on the three gears in uBlock Origin, then go over to "My Filters" and paste the above line into the page below and then click "Apply Chnages"

Comment: This answer makes the actual internet as a whole better. What a gem.