# What risks are you taking when "signing in with Google"?

Tags: security, website, privacy, google-accounts

(Sorry if this is too basic, I'm not a web dev)

When a third-party web site offers you to "sign in with Google", what risks are you taking: Are you just giving it (the third party) your name and gmail address, or are you giving it anything else just by signing in?

Comment: Feel free to explain the down-vote(s).

Comment: This question is more suitable for security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Gantendo More so than the other 5298 questions here: https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/security ?

Comment: pretty sure that when that site was started no one wanted to move all the existing questions

Comment: Useful link : [How can I block the “Sign in with Google” prompt on websites?](https://superuser.com/questions/1773208/how-can-i-block-the-sign-in-with-google-prompt-on-websites)

Comment: This is not a bad question, but it is not a good fit here. To be fully explored this needs discussion, back and forth, multiple viewpoints, because it comes down to lots of data points and then a judgement call by each person. To be best answered this question needs a forum, rather than this QA site. Not a bad question, just this is not the right place for it to be fully explored.

Comment: @MWB: Questions related to security and computer hardware / operating system remain on-topic here, even if they would also be on-topic at security.stackexchange.com.   But your question relates (only) to websites, and therefore it is off-topic here.

Comment: Related [Is authentication using Facebook/Google considered good practice?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/153446/292440), [Google Accounts login - is it good enough for financial services?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/84165/292440), [Why don't some services offer Google/Facebook/Apple/Twitter login](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/254576/292440)

Comment: [How to disable Google One Tap sign-up prompts?](https://superuser.com/q/1414410/1794161)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click on that button, it will redirect to Google's sign in page, and once you sign in, Google should show you what information of your Google account is shared. Some websites might also allow you to enable/disable the sharing of certain info.

Most social media apps should just need name, email, avatar. Other apps might need more depending on what they do/want.

Comment: Strange. I just did it, but I didn't see any permissions menu.

Comment: "When you click on that button, it will redirect to Google's sign in page" is how it is supposed to work.  However you as the website visitor have very little recourse if the webpage spoofs the sign-in page instead of using the genuine Google one.

Comment: @BenVoigt You can check the URL.

Answer (score 7):

As @Tetsujin mentions, you share personal data with Google they would not otherwise have. You also share with the other account information from Google that they would not otherwise have.

Another risk is that you have inserted a dependency of requiring that particular Google account to access and use your other account. You lose access to your other account if you lose access to your Google account, or the other account stops supporting Google sign-in, or if Google drops that other service due to legal / political / other issues.

If your Google account gets hacked or breached, you put the other account at risk.

If you use sign in with Google on a lot of other accounts, you have a pretty large single point of failure.

Comment: Many of these risks would also seem to apply if I create a separate account on that website and enter a Gmail address there. Then too I am telling Google I am registering on that website (because they send me a confirmation email), anyone with access to my Google account can reset the password, and I lose access to my account if I forget the password and no longer have access to my Google account. Am I mistaken in any of these points?

Comment: @wonderbear: Note that "if I forget the password and no longer have access to my Google account" is now two faults; it is "single fault tolerant".  Whereas "login with Google" has a single point of failure.

Comment: If you register with a Gmail address, Google only gets sender, subject, or contents if they scrape your emails, something they claim not to do for ads / personalization.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider the main 'risk' being that by using the service, you are contributing your personal 'interest list' to an organisation whose entire raison d'être is to sell targeted advertising to 3rd parties.

I would see that as sufficient reason to never use this type of service.

Comment: It is 'a' risk but not the most severe one.

Comment: Google sells targeted ads, obviously. But I'm assuming that it's all anonymized.